# Taylor series of $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ converges to $\arctan(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I have to find out the Taylor series of $f(x) = \arctan(x)$ and prove that it converges to $f(x)$ for any $x \in (-1, 1) $.

So far I determined the Taylor series to $T_f(x) = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1} $ . With the ratio test, I proved convergence for $x^2 \lt 1$ which is satisfied by the domain of definition of $x$.

But how do I continue proving that $T_f(x)$ converges to $\arctan(x)$ for $-1 \lt x \lt 1$ ? 
Splitting up the series in positive and negative parts didn't help me either.

**EDIT**: I just noticed the following:

$T_f = \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k+1}}{4k+1} - \sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4k+3}}{4k+3} $ is the series split up in a positive and negative one. If I derive both, I get $T'_f = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x^{4k} - \sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} x^2 x^{4k}$ ; can I apply the formula for geometric series here?

**EDIT 2** : If I apply $\sum \limits_{k=0}^{\infty} a_0 q^k $ with $x^{4k} = (x^4)^k $ thus $q=x^4$ I get  $T'_f = \frac{1}{1-x^4} - \frac{x^2}{1-x^4} = \frac{1-x^2}{(1-x^2)(1+x^2)} = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ which is the exact derivative of $\arctan(x)$. What do you think about that?

Comment: Don't you have the theorem that a taylor series converges to the function at it's points of continuity iff it converges?

Comment: $x^2<1$ implies that $-1<x<1$

Comment: AlexR, No, I don't :( 
janmarqz, yes I know it's just written differently

Comment: @Christian So you've shown that it converges, but not that it converges to arctan, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. Note my edit, does it help if I show that the derivative of the Taylor series is equal to the derivative of $\arctan'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1} $ ?

Comment: Probably the easiest approach is to prove that where the Taylor series of a function converges absolutely, you can integrate term by term, then note that the Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ converges absolutely on $(-1,1)$, then integrate term by term to get your result. After that you need to say something about uniqueness of power series to guarantee that this series must actually be the Maclaurin series of $\arctan$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{2n+1}}=1$$ proves that the radius of convergence of the power series is $1$.

After that, for any $x\in(-1,1)$ we may notice that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1} = \int_{0}^{x}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n t^{2n}\,dt = \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{t^2+1}=\arctan(x)$$
and we're done.